Are there any good or interesting critiques to Nagarjuna's philosophy
After studying him I found in him some of the most brilliant and conclusive arguments about "reality" and whatever it emerges from it. But I wish to know if there are any critiques that either proves him completely wrong, or modifies some of his (non)-thesis.

He was pivotal in the development of Mahayana thought, comparable to Aquinas or Maimonides or Shankaracharya. Like sure they aren't everyone's cup of tea even in their own lineages, but their impact is simply a fact any serious student in it needs to study. More interesting to look at what Nagarjuna was doing in his own context, & find parallels to Western thought eg 'Nāgārjuna, Nietzsche, and Rorty’s Strange Looping Trick' https://absoluteirony.wordpress.com/2014/09/17/nagarjuna-nietzsche-rorty-and-their-strange-looping-trick Many key Mahayana texts still lack good translations

'Good' and 'interesting' are in the eye of the beholder. Sion has some sharp words in Buddhist Illogic, although based on reading Nagarjuna perhaps too literally:"He uses double standards, applying or ignoring the laws of thought and other norms as convenient to his goals; he manipulates his readers, by giving seemingly logical form (like the dilemma) to his discourse, while in fact engaged in non-sequiturs or appealing to doubtful premises; he plays with words, relying on unclear terminology, misleading equivocations and unfair fixations of meaning..."

I wouldn't really call Nagarjuna's corpus 'philosophy'. It seems like coming at it the wrong way.

The life of Milarepa is another subject you might enjoy.

@Conifold, nice! It seems uncertain, when studying Buddhism, whether it's Gautama or Nagarjuna. I know they (I think I know) weren't contemporaries though.

@Hudjefa: They were around 750 years apart, & had very different styles & concerns. I don't know of any uncertainties between them, except in instagrammed quote-posters that usually are misatributing things neither said.

@ScottRowe: It's philosophy like Aquinas is philosophy.

V v well said @CriglCragl. Aquinas : ✓ ; Nagarjuna :  ×  Shankara :  ×, Lao Tzu : ×. And if it's pointed out this looks like a quite Christian site, some get mighty piqued

@CriglCragl, we may save Buddhism then, by disowning one of its famous scholars. I don't know how far this is true, but at one point Buddhists outdebated the Hindus (there were ultimate rap battles between them I suppose, probably in front of kings & queens), but then later on the tables turned. The details are probably buried in mountains of obscure texts.

The main criticism to Nagarjuna is that he does not articulate his opinion in a clear and distinct way.

@Hudjefa: What are you on about? Nagarjuna shaped every major branch of Mahayana Buddhism, inextricably, because he solved some of the major theological conundrums of his era. You imply 'we' should forsake Mahayana Buddhism? When was it made 'ours'? Buddhist scholars have always out-debated Hindu thinkers, Shankaracharya responded to the Buddhist challenge by copying a lot. Records of the debates generally only survives in Buddhist literature, what survived from Nalanda. Buddhists memorised more, & put more emphasis on texts.

@Conifold a reading by Juan Arnau says being "illogic" is exactly the point, thus, any critique is actually defending it.

@dawn From what I understand, Sion is not charging Nagarjuna with illogic as such, he is charging him with using illogic for disingenuous and manipulative purposes. It may well be unfair, but defending Nagarjuna by saying that was his point would not be wise.
